# changings gas logs fireplace to insert

Tags: fireplace

This is more like asking opinion whether it is worth converting from a gas logs fireplace to a fireplace insert. It is gonna cost me 5k here in seattle.

I have a gas logs fireplace (gas fireplace with open vent in front and chimney to the top). I am thinking to replace it with a modern fireplace insert. The room is around 400 sq ft. My question is it worth putting in 5k to put a fireplace insert instead.

Basically, if the gas logs fireplace can heat up the 400 sq ft, then I won't need a fireplace insert. Its just that I am not sure whether it would be able to heat the 400 sq ft.

Comment: Sorry need more information to help.  State your situation as if you were speaking to a child, clear and full sentences.  Give me some details.

Comment: how about now ?

Comment: Worth in what sense? Energy usage? Comfort? Appearance? Resale? As it is the question is too subjective and broad for our Q&A format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about a gas log set in a masonry fireplace then you need to understand that these log sets are not really expected to heat the room aside from a bit of passive radiant.  In fact, the room could experience a net loss in heat.  The flame from the gas log will heat the chimney flue causing a good draft and will suck the heat right out of the room. These things were designed for ambiance without the mess of chopping wood. They are quick and clean.  That is it.

Ben Franklin designed the Franklin stove to beat the disaster of a heat source of the old masonry fireplace.

The modern natural gas steel fireplace insert is a big step forward.  It will actually make heat.  They have been engineered to extract heat from the fire and get it into the room.  With the right size they can easily heat a typical room of a 1000-Sq feet.
It is however not necessarily the most beautiful thing that ever walked the down the isle. Some have glass fronts to give you a view of the fire.

Cost effectiveness? Something you have to decide.

Comment: What about installing a blower in the gas logs fireplace? Would that work to get the air ?

Comment: You can't be serious.  Those yellow flame are full of CO.